# Why can't I override Bootstrap default value?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}">
  </head>
  <body



  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="bootstrap-overrides">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="{% static "images/download.jpeg" %}" width="90" height="90" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#top"></a>Patients Page</li>
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'first_app:form_name' %}">Register Patients</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
</nav>

    <div class="container">
      {% block body_block %}

      {% endblock %}

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

```
h1{
  color: red;
}

#bootstrap-overrides {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

I want my navbar to be flexed row-wise rather than the bootstrap default of column-wise. I tried to override the bootstrap default however no matter what I did, it didnt work. It is almost like HTML doesnt see my CSS. Funny thing is, h1 is actually red so I know HTML respects the CSS. But not for navbar. I tried using more specific identification, didnt work. I also tried using !important; and it didnt work either. What might be the problem?

Full project: https://github.com/gokceozer/healthCenter

Comment: It seems to be align row-wise to me...

Comment: You need to provide an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
.container ul {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

or give all code

Comment: Can you change the background color for this container or ul? Because your H1 is in a different file